# Rounding up/down when using levels to determine number of uses of an ability

Tags: pathfinder-1e, rogue

For abilities that read "[a character] can use this ability one additional time per day for every *n* [class] levels he possesses", does one round up or down?

Example: Rogue Ability [Honeyed Words](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-talents/honeyed-words-ex) from the Advanced Player's Guide (*not* to be confused with the trait of the same name) says it is allowed one additional use per day for every 5 rogue levels.  So, if I'm level 6 is that 1 use or 2 per day?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Pathfinder, unless otherwise specified, [all rounding rounds down](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Rounding). The cited rogue ability does not specify otherwise. It does, however, specify one use baseline, plus an additional one use per 5 levels. Therefore, a level 6 rogue would get 1 additional use per day based on her level, for a total of 2 uses per day.